# SQL Query (joins between tables)

Tags: sql, join

there is two tables: country , countrylanguage and the common columns are ***code*** in country table and ***countrycode*** in countrylanguage.
how to retrieve the name of country and count of spoken language in each.
here is what I wrote:

```
    select country.name , countrylanguage.language from country , countrylangauge where countrylanguage.language in (select count(language) from countrylanguage group by countrycode);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I got error, so there is no sample data

Comment: sample data means the data being used. If you are getting an error, _post it_

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ANSI compliant database engine (c.f. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Interoperability_and_standardization)), you can use `JOIN ... ON` to join both tables based on the code columns.

```
SELECT country.name,
       count(countrylanguage.language) AS language_count
FROM   country
       JOIN countrylanguage ON country.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
```

This performs an [inner join](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join), so only the records present in both `country` and `countrylanguage`tables will be returned. You can use `OUTER JOIN` otherwise.

If you are using a database which does not support ANSI joins, the join can be performed in a `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT country.name,
       count(countrylanguage.language) AS language_count
FROM   country,
       countrylanguage 
WHERE  country.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following script-

```
SELECT A.name country_name,
B.language,
COUNT(B.language) total_count
FROM country A 
INNER JOIN countrylangauge B ON A.Code = B.countrycode 
GROUP BY A.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to take into account that countries could have no languages, you should use a `left join`:

```
select c.name, count(cl.language) as num_languages
from country c left join
     countrylangauge cl
     on cl.countrycode = c.countrycode
group by c.countrycode, c.name;
```

You appear to be learning SQL.  If so, you should not be learning about commas in the `FROM` clause *at all*.  You should only be learning about `JOIN`, which is the proper way to join tables together.